# Why does my Arduino fail to connect to my Mosca Broker?

Tags: arduino, mqtt, azure-web-app-service, broker, mosca

I am learning MQTT and I deployed the open source mosca broker to an azure web app. The problem is the broker works between 2 pcs but When I try to connect my arduino nano to the broker it always fails. Here is my server code:

```
//Mosca
const mosca = require('mosca')
const settings = {
   http: {
    // port for websockets, MQTT is running in default port 1883
    port: 8000,
    bundle: true,
    static: './public'
  }
}

// start mosca
const moscaServer = new mosca.Server(settings)
moscaServer.on('ready', setup)

// fired when the mqtt server is ready
function setup() {
  console.log('Mosca server is up and running in port 1883!')
  console.log('Using port 8000 for MQTT over Web-Sockets!')
}

// fired when a client is connected
moscaServer.on('clientConnected', function(client) {
  console.log('client connected', client.id)
})

// fired when a message is received
moscaServer.on('published', function(packet, client) {
  //if (packet.topic == '/example') {
    console.log(packet.payload.toString('utf-8'))
  //}
})

// fired when a client subscribes to a topic
moscaServer.on('subscribed', function(topic, client) {
  console.log('subscribed : ', topic)
})

// fired when a client unsubscribes to a topic
moscaServer.on('unsubscribed', function(topic, client) {
  console.log('unsubscribed : ', topic)
})

// fired when a client is disconnecting
moscaServer.on('clientDisconnecting', function(client) {
  console.log('clientDisconnecting : ', client.id)
})

// fired when a client is disconnected
moscaServer.on('clientDisconnected', function(client) {
  console.log('clientDisconnected : ', client.id)
})
```

Comment: Given you say this works from a PC, why do you think the mosca code is at fault and not the code running in the Arduino?

Comment: Yeah, what hardilib said.  Which code has the error?  Post that code! And, tell us what "always fails" actually means? What error? Is there an error code? How does it fail?!?

Answer (score 0):

From Azure App Service WebApp stand-point - by default, App Service assumes your custom container is listening on port 80. If your container listens to a different port, set the WEBSITES_PORT app setting in your App Service app.

A WebApp can be accessed via the internet is through the already-exposed HTTP (80) and HTTPS (443) TCP ports.

App Service currently allows your container to expose only one port for HTTP requests.
I’m not much sure about - MQTT broker. Also, how exactly you're attempting to connect.

From App Service- Docker Compose options-Kindly checkout the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#configure-multi-container-apps), Supported and Unsupported configuration.
•   Only one container can be open for access
•   Only port 80 and 8080 is accessible (exposed ports)

Kindly refer [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#configure-port-number) for more details.

Note: Web Sockets are supported on Linux apps.